# IIS 7 redirects to IP

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, domain, redirection, cpanel, iis-7

On the domain cpanel, I have subdomain A record pointing to the IIS server IP, but once the subdomain is accessed, the browser is redirected to the IP, and it is shown in the address bar. How to force it to show the subdomain?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sgsw4.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting would not work for what you want. You need to do reverse proxy and your server to passthrough your subdomain requests to your other server. I don't know if the cpanel you use has that option.

Edit: I just read again and saw the A record. If that works then your IIS server seems to redirect you to the ip. Can you check in you browser from where you get the 3xx message.

[This](https://templatetoaster.com/tutorials/iis-set-domain-name/) guide can help you config iis to accept you domain

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your response. The A redirect is done but still no luck.